# What suggestion can you make to amazon website in an automatized smoke test Selenium IDE Google Chrome extension?

Tags: selenium-ide, recommendation-engine, smoke-testing

What suggestion can you make to amazon website in an automatized smoke test Selenium IDE Google Chrome extension ?

i tried googling: " What suggestion can you make to amazon website in an automatized smoke test Selenium IDE Google Chrome extension ? ", i found a solution in https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/documents/downloadPublic?documentIds=080166e5bbdb1f72&appId=PPGMS, because the results says recommendations fro amazon, but when i search in Adobe Acrobat DC PRO for recommendations i can find that, and the text is huge, someone could answer my question ?